# How to force Vue to detect array changes done within async method with a forEach loop?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, foreach, vue-reactivity

I'm using a v-for loop on the template but even though the v-for loop feeds all items with same data object `userCollections`, only the ones I call the function from get their lengths and items updated. I'm rendering one button on each item to call the function. In summary the line below updates the array BUT only the one item within the v-for loop that calls the function. They all start the with the same global array, but then when I add more items to that array (from within each item), it's like each item has their own `userCollections` array, even though I'm updating the "global" Vue data object: `userCollections`...

```
 this.userCollections.push({id: doc.id, ...doc.data()})
```

My template:

```
 <div v-for="(col, index) in userCollections" :id="col.id" :ref="col.id" class="collRow" @click="addToCollection($event, col.id)">             
    <p >{{col.name}} </p>
               
    <p v-if="col.shortDescription">{{col.shortDescription}}</p>
    <button @click=refreshUserColl(userAddress)>refresh</button>
</div>
```

As stated in Vue's documetantion, Vue cannot detect some changes to arrays: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html?redirect=true#For-Arrays
I'm assuming this is the root of my problem, so I'm trying to use a workaround suggested on the link. I'm using a forEach loop and I'm struggling to get the right syntax.
My code:

```
async refreshUserColl(userAddress) {
    let vm = this
    let collsRefs = collection(db, "users", userAddress, 'Collections'); // getting data from Google Firestore
    const qSnap = await getDocs(collsRefs);
    this.userCollections = []
    qSnap.docs.forEach((doc) =>{
        console.log(this)
        
        this.set(vm.userCollections.push({id: doc.id, ...doc.data()})) <--- problem
    })
    
}
```

notice the `this.SET(vm.userCollections...)` which is basically me bluntly trying to translate the instructions on Vue's documentation `Vue.set(vm.items, indexOfItem, newValue)`

I'm getting this error
[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `Vue.set` is not the same as `this.set` for a a start, and `Vue.set` takes three arguments, and you're supplying one - as that page you linked to says, you need to use `this.$set(vm.items, indexOfItem, newValue)` ... `$set` not `set` - though, you're pushing to an array, so you shouldn't be needing any workarounds

Comment: Thanks @Bravo. Would you then suggest any way translate this:  this.userCollections.push({id: doc.id, ...doc.data()}) to that vue.set pattern? I'm completely lost.

Comment: I don't think you need to - since pushing to an array doesn't require the workaround

Comment: damn.... maybe there's another reason why userCollections is not updating across all items in the v-for loop and I can't even see it.

Comment: One problem each item's "refresh" button's click handler is bound to `refreshUserColl(userAddress)`, and there's only one `userAddress` for all of them. How is `userAddress` determined?

Comment: @tony19 yes, it's the same for all of them. It's fetched from the database (Google Firestore) and returned asynchronously  on the await getDocs(collsRefs) function

Comment: @tony19 more to your question: `userAddress` it's coming an argument from the function that calls `refreshUserColl` – then `refreshUserColl` uses it to get the  `userCollections` array.